# Form square matrix out of a non square matrix to calculate determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have a 4x3 matrix and want to determine if the columns of my matrix are linearly independent. Is there a way to form a square matrix (4x4) in order get the ability to calculate the determinant and see if they are linearly independent?

Comment: Point $3$ of the answer above is what you might like: $A=B^t$ and then $\det(BA)$ gives the result.

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't tried row reduction?

Comment: Yes you are right the 3rd point is what i was looking for.
Row reduction would be better indeed...